# How to get the training and validation accuacy of the model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to grab the training and validation accuracy values, but it is not returning `acc` and `val_acc` values.

```
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'RMSprop',
              lr = 0.001,
              metrices = ['accuracy'])

# prepare the generators
train_gen = train_datagen.flow(training_images, 
                               training_labels,
                               batch_size = 64
                              )

validation_gen = validation_datagen.flow(testing_images, 
                               testing_labels,
                               batch_size = 64
                              )
    
# Train the Model
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                              epochs = 20,
                              validation_data = validation_gen
                      )
```

Comment: What language and framework is this?

Comment: Language is pyhton and framework is tensorflow. Thanks for looking at it, but I got the solution ,there is a typo error in model.compile. """model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'RMSprop',
              lr = 0.001,
              metrics = ['accuracy'])"""

Comment: it is 'metrics' not 'metrices' in mdoel.compile ..